# Encrypt mailSettings in Web.config

Tags: web-config

i want to ask about to encrypt mailSettings section under system.net

[image]

but, when i try to encrypt by cmd.exe it seems that they cannot find mailSettings

[image]

i use this script

"aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "mailSettings" "D:\website" -prov ConnectionTestProvider"

can someone help me to encrypt this part?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found the solution. you need to specify path for mailSettings for this one

"aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "system.net/mailSettings/smtp" "D:\website" -prov ConnectionTestProvider"

[image]

after try and find solution for days.

Answer (score 4):

CMD -> run as administrator

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

---FOR CONNECTIONSTRINGS---

ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\namefoldersite" -> CRIPT
ASPNET_REGIIS -pdf "connectionStrings" "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\namefoldersite" -> DECRIPT


---FOR MAILSETTING---

ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "system.net/mailSettings/smtp" "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\namefoldersite" -> CRIPT
ASPNET_REGIIS -pdf "system.net/mailSettings/smtp" "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\namefoldersite" -> DECRIPT
```